# Is it possible to automatically create a list item when a file is added in a folder on a computer?

Tags: file, storage, item-added

I use a sharepoint site to deal with escalation tickets. I want to attach files to those tickets. BUT I cannot use the magical "attach files" parameters because files would be stored on sharepoint and I only have 100Mb memory space.

My solution is to create another list (called Escalation_Documents) in which I add the files (File title, escalation id, link to open it, path, and so on). Those files are then displayed on my escalation display form by using an infopath form, a query data connection and a repeating section.
So it works fine, but I'm lazy and I would love something : when I add my linked file in the right folder on my computer, I would like to automatically create the related item in my Escalation_Documents list.
So is it possible or not? And if yes, how?

I'm a newby to sharepoint, I don't have access to the code in sharepoint Designer (my boss with the password and permission is away for two weeks).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know much about desktop app programming, but in theory you could do a few different things:

- Code a context menu (item right click) option that uploads to SharePoint, by calling an app or whatever coded in Visual C#
- Write a CSOM script in Powershell that can be run manually against a given file, or configured as a scheduled task to check a given folder for new items and upload them to SharePoint

In terms of ease to achieve, the second one would be best.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The second one seems also to be better but I have absolutely no idea how to do it... And I think it would take as much time to run the script than to go the list and add an item, doesn't it?

Comment: You are probably best doing that for this purpose, it is a lot of work when there is an existing method. It's a nice idea though. I would reccomend learning more about CSOM in Powershell though as it's a useful skill for SP, especially in Office 365 where there is no server-side object model.

Comment: Yes maybe I'll learn about it but I'm only an intern and I was asked to develop something simple, so that when I leave my coworkers will be able to debug everything easily... If I put complicated code everywhere they won't be able to do it... Thanks again!